# How to connect the application container to the mysql containier

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having an application service and a MySQL service but I am not able to connect the two containers and it keeps returning me this error
`jango.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")`

I have included the links in my application service but nothing is working out.

Mine MySQL container is working up fine and even I can log into the MySQL container.

Here is the snapshot of the services:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                              NAMES
cc26d09a81d1        gmasmatrix_worker:latest        "/entrypoint.sh /sta…"   17 seconds ago      Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                                      gmasmatrix_celeryworker_1
749f23c37b16        gmasmatrix_application:latest   "/entrypoint.sh /sta…"   18 seconds ago      Exited (1) 9 seconds ago                                       gmasmatrix_application_1
666029ad063a        gmasmatrix_flower               "/entrypoint.sh /sta…"   18 seconds ago      Exited (1) 10 seconds ago                                      gmasmatrix_flower_1
50ac0497e66b        mysql:5.7.10                    "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   21 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds               0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             gmasmatrix_db_1
669fbbe0a81d        mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0          "MailHog"                21 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds               1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp   gmasmatrix_mailhog_1
235a46c8d453        redis:5.0                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds               6379/tcp                           gmasmatrix_redis_1
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:

  application: &application
    image: gmasmatrix_application:latest
    command: /start.sh
    volumes:
    - .:/app
#    env_file:
#    - .env
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
#    cpu_shares: 874
#    mem_limit: 1610612736
#    mem_reservation: 1610612736
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/application/Dockerfile
      args:
      - GMAS_ENV_TYPE=local
    links:
      - "db"


  celeryworker:
    <<: *application
    image: gmasmatrix_worker:latest
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker
    links:
      - "db"


  flower:
    <<: *application
    image: gmasmatrix_flower
    ports:
    - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
    links:
      - "db"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    ports:
    - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.10
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gmas_mkt
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pulkit1607
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
``
```

Comment: Where do you configure the location of your database?  That's not shown in this `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` - which in docker points to the app container itself.

Instead you should use the IP of the `db` container. You can utilize the built-in docker DNS service to do this. In your application configuration, use `db` (the name of the mysql container) as the host to connect to instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Basically your app is trying to connect to the wrong IP, you need to find the correct IP - of the `db` container